# What about 'nested' components in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular 2+ versions, how can I solve a problem like this?

I have some data, what I got from the server. I iterate over the array of data,and I want to display each objects. So (for example) if I have a list of the registrated users, and I want to display a list of the users, what is the correct solution?

1, I need an another Angular component for the list elements (which contains the user informations, and the related functions) 
2,or I just use a simple loop, and parse data to a template?

Comment: You may want to look into how to store your user data within the Angular application's "state".  Additionally , I would use ngFor directive for iterating over the loop. Dont use a traditional for loop because the ngFor will optimize things for you. You need to be careful if the size of the array is very big. In that case you can use the trackBy directive. Ill try to find a good example somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally up to you.  I would choose option 2 for simplicity.

```
// some.component.ts
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  users = {};

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = this.data.getUserInformation();
  }

}
```

-

```
// some.component.html
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <p>user.name</p>
  ...
</div>
```